# Specificity of the immune system

Tags: immunology

We know that the adaptive immune system recognizes foreign particles when their proteins are expessed of the the surface of T-cells, complexed with MHCs. But MHCs present only short peptides of length 8-11 amino acids long. How is it that every antigen has one characteristic 8-11 residues long stretch in some protein of its which none of the host's protein has. Conversely, how is it that this 8-11 amino acid long peptide, which the body is recognizing as foreign is not found in any protein of any cell of our body?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, your conception of antigen presentation seems a bit off, but that's not the crux of your question. There's around 10^15 different sequence permutations for a peptide 11-mer. Despite that, it's actually likely that highly conserved regions of some proteins will be present in both the pathogen and the host. T cells will not recognize them, however, as they are negatively selected in the thymus.

Comment: This is not completely true. One part of the adaptive immune system actively recognizes and tolerates own oligopeptides.

Comment: @inf3rno Which component is that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_T_cell "Regulatory T cells are involved in shutting down immune responses after they have successfully eliminated invading organisms, and also in preventing autoimmunity cells." - Ofc. most of the self-reactive T-cells are destroyed by negative selection, or probably (I guess) transformed into regulatory T-cells. I have to read more in the topic, but it's too complex, I have to write a program, which can maintain a knowledge graph.

Comment: Another part of the puzzle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_B_cells

Comment: @inf3rno I don't think Tregs can be said to be actively recognizing self antigens. It seems that Treg recognition of self is an exception rather than the rule.

Comment: I would rather say that your model is coarse-grained, while this one is fine-grained, but you are right, most of the T cells do not behave that way. +1

Comment: @canadianer yea, it should be APCs, wrote T-cell by mistake. One more thing, how did you arrive upon 10^15?

Comment: @Bio_geek24 Very rough rounding of 20^11

Answer (score 2):

The immune system is the most beautiful, complex biological process that operates on a scale that it can be termed as engineering.

**MHC polymorphism:**

MHC's have two particular properties that give it flexibility in the face of the antigen: Its polygenicitcy (it contains several different MHC class I and MHC class II genes with different ranges of peptide-binding specificities) and secondly, MHCs are polymorphic (having multiple variants of each gene within the population).

```
Note: MHCs are also called HLA (Human Leukocyte Antigen)
```

[image]

So as you can see, there is a lot of possible variation possible. I'd recommend reading through this:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27156/

From the source above:

> The outstanding feature of the MHC molecules is their extensive
>   polymorphism. This polymorphism is of critical importance in antigen
>   recognition by T cells. A T cell recognizes antigen as a peptide bound
>   by a particular allelic variant of an MHC molecule, and will not
>   recognize the same peptide bound to other MHC molecules.
>
> This behavior of T cells is called MHC restriction. Most MHC alleles
>   differ from one another by multiple amino acid substitutions, and
>   these differences are focused on the peptide-binding site and adjacent
>   regions that make direct contact with the T-cell receptor.
>
> At least three properties of MHC molecules are affected by MHC
>   polymorphism: the range of peptides bound; the conformation of the
>   bound peptide; and the direct interaction of the MHC molecule with the
>   T-cell receptor. Thus the highly polymorphic nature of the MHC has
>   functional consequences, and the evolutionary selection for this
>   polymorphism suggests that it is critical to the role of the MHC
>   molecules in the immune response.

Comment: While a good explanation, this does not address the question.

Comment: @canadianer Apologies, misread the question. Editing the answer now.